# How can I canonicalize Windows file paths in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, filepath, backslash

**Update:**

I can make this a simpler problem to solve:

I want to figure out what the correct regex would be to substitute any single occurrence of a back slash with two back slashes.

I want to turn this:

```
vlc.plugin.path = C:\Program Files\JekyllV0.9.2\\VLC_1.0.0\\plugins
```

into:

```
vlc.plugin.path = C:\\Program Files\\JekyllV0.9.2\\VLC_1.0.0\\plugins
```

**Original question:**

I want to change the following in a file using a Perl Regex:

- all occurrences of a single back slash to two back slashes
- all occurrences of a single forward slash to two back slashes

I tried the following:

```
perl" -p -i.orig -e "s#\\#\\\\#g" -e "s#/#\\\\#g" %VIDEOLOG_PROPERTIES_FILE%
```

where %VIDEOLOG_PROPERTIES_FILE% contains:

```
vlc.plugin.path = C:\Program Files\JekyllV0.9.2/VLC_1.0.0/plugins
```

Comment: Not sure how MSWindows handles these things, but you may want to try escaping all your backslashes once more s#\\\\#\\\\\\\\#g

Comment: "... and what happened? – chaos". yeah, that's what Perl do. (just kidding i like Perl ;-))

Comment: Perl responded with:  

syntax error at -e line 2, near "s#/#\\#g"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: No, he's effectively doubling all his backslashes, even for the sequences that have two backslashes.

Comment: @Axeman, not sure what you mean. I was thinking that perl sees 's#\\#\\\\#' as 's#\#\\#' (invalid) after unescaping, the way it would in a unix shell. Looking at the answers that seems not to be the problem however.

Comment: I think the word is "canonize"

Comment: Only if the Catholic Church would like to submit an opinion!

Comment: @chaos, your edit to the title might be more precise than the original, but not as clear to the less experienced.  I have updated the tags in an attempt to aid those less in the know.

Answer (score 6):

For the basic replace:

```
perl -p -i.orig -e "s#[/\\]#\\\\#g" %VIDEOLOG_PROPERTIES_FILE%
```

To replace only slashes and backslashes that do not appear adjacent to another instance of the same character:

```
perl -p -i.orig -e "s#(?<!/)/(?!/)#\\\\#g; s#(?<\\)\\(?!\\)#\\\\#g" %VIDEOLOG_PROPERTIES_FILE%
```

Comment: Can you explain why that would work differently from what Faust already tried?

Comment: @Rob: well, to begin with, it doesn't produce a syntax error. As Eevee says in his answer, you could fix that by adding a semi-colon to the first substitution. Chaos makes the two regexes simpler by combining them in the character class.

Comment: When I use what you suggested I get: vlc.plugin.path = C:\\Program Files\\JekyllV0.9.2\\\\VLC_1.0.0\\\\plugins

Is there a way to avoid changing the existing "\\" to "\\\\"?

Comment: Yeah, edited for solution that will only replace lone instances.

Answer (score 4):

You want [`File::Spec->canonpath`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Spec).

**Update::** Actually, that was the wrong recommendation. That will work for internal function calls etc but it will write single backslashes to the file. However, the following will work better:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::INI::Reader;

my $config = Config::INI::Reader->read_handle(\*DATA);

my $var1 = $config->{_}->{'vlc.plugin.path1'};
my $var2 = $config->{_}->{'vlc.plugin.path2'};

for my $v ($var1, $var2) {
    $v =~ s! (?: [\\]{1,2} ) | (?:/) !\\\\!gx;
    print "$v\n";
}

__DATA__
vlc.plugin.path1 = C:\Program Files\JekyllV0.9.2\\VLC_1.0.0\\plugins
vlc.plugin.path2 = C:\Program Files\JekyllV0.9.2/VLC_1.0.0/plugins
```

Output:

```
C:\\Program Files\\JekyllV0.9.2\\VLC_1.0.0\\plugins
C:\\Program Files\\JekyllV0.9.2\\VLC_1.0.0\\plugins
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was very instructive and useful.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure Perl blindly concatenates all its `-e` arguments, so those are being squashed into `s#\\#\\\\#gs#/#\\\\#g`, and then the second regex looks like a comment.

It works for me if I change it to `-e 's#\\#\\\\#g; s#/#\\\\#g'`.

Of course, you could do this with a single regex, since you're using the same replacement both times.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work, because perl doesn't handle two `-e` flags--without a semicolon  "between" the two commands. You have to write it as below (if you lose the d-quote right after 'perl', that is.)

```
perl -p -i.orig -e "s#\\#\\\\#g;" -e "s#/#\\\\#g" %VIDEOLOG_PROPERTIES_FILE%
```

I do something similar, but because Perl supports `'/'` on the PC, my preference is for forward slashes. So I use the following :

```
s![\\/]+!/!g;
```

Thus it can be easily turned around to

```
s![\\/]+!\\\\!g;
```

Now a word about why I do that: sometimes people can't figure out whether or not they should put a slash on the beginning or end of parts of paths that will be concatenated. At times you end up with even double forward slashes. (But not if you use [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec).) thus it's good to handle those kinds of collisions. Especially because it's going to be a path, we want to take however many slashes of whatever kind and turn them into the kind we like.

Additionally, I even do this:

```
s!([\\/]+([.][\\/]+)?)+!/!g
```

Because it captures those cases where it's the same cluster of slashes separated by a dot which does nothing, because path-wise `/` <=> `(/+.)+` for those programs and scripts that handle the dots in path names, while the other programs will error out.

Comment: This isn't really right.  Perl handles two `-e` clauses just fine; what it doesn't do is insert an implicit semicolon between them.

Comment: @chaos You are *absolutely* right, color me surprised that I've got to tell Perl to put a command separator there. I've always gone with the functional assumption that it doesn't work. But I tried it and it worked on all the platforms I tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[21:09:00][mgrad@zuza-3:~]$ perl -pe 's#\/#\/\/#g; s#\\#\\\\#g' test.txt
vlc.plugin.path = C:\\Program Files\\JekyllV0.9.2//VLC_1.0.0//plugins
```