# use Win32::Process; My output reports 'The system cannot find the path specified'

Tags: perl, win32-process

I am relearning Perl after about 10 years of non use.

I did a copy and paste of the two scripts below from one of the answers for a similar question on this site. I have checked and double checked the `path` and tried several deviations, but I still get the same answer -

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It does get to the `starting child process` and the exits with the error message `The system cannot find the path specified`.

Below is the cut and paste of the original two scripts

parent.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use warnings;

use Win32;
use Win32::Process;

$| = 1;

my $p;

print "Starting child process ... \n";

Win32::Process::Create(
    $p,
    'c:\Perl\perl.exe',
    'perl hello.pl',
    1,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
    '.',
) or die Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );

print "Waiting three seconds before killing 'hello.pl'\n";

for (1 .. 3) {
    print;
    sleep 1;
}
$p->Kill(0)
    or die "Cannot kill '$p'";
```

hello.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$| = 1;

print "Hello World\n";
print "Sleeping 1000 seconds\n";

for (1 .. 1000) {
    sleep 1;
    print '.';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslashes in your path, or use forward slashes.

Look at this [somewhat related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308152/how-can-i-canonicalize-windows-file-paths-in-perl).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your effort, but this did not work.

I tried c:/Perl/perl.exe

c:\\Perl\\perl.exe

and even c:\/Perl\/perl.exe just for fun :-}

Comment: It seems that you pasted Unix scripts. I don't use perl much, but this line I believe will not work in Windows:  #!/usr/bin/perl 
Here are some Windows examples:
http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/problem-with-win32-process-create-360040.html

Answer (score 0):

(This answer will be edited as conditions check out)

1. check that there is a `c:\Perl directory` - it may be case-sensitive (eg. `C:\` not `c:\`)
2. make sure there's a `perl.exe` listed in that directory, the actual path might be `C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe`
3. `'perl hello.pl'` may need to be the full qualified perl path (eg 
   `'C:\Perl\perl.exe hello.pl'`)

**Side Note:**

1. Since you're using single-quotes (`'`) you shouldn't need to escape your backslash (`\`)
2. If processing
   on windows you may change:
   `#!/usr/bin/perl` to the specified
   windows path `#!C:\Perl\perl.exe` ,
   however I don't think this really matters as
   much on windows, it just helps you know where the executable is for times like this.